# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method' Im not sure what this means

Tags: python

--This function's purpose is to compute the Carmichael function--
I have tried to add n = int(n) to the top of the function and directly convert n to an int in the conditionals but I still get a similar error. I do not understand why the program does not interpret n as an integer

```
def carmichael(n: int) -> int:
  k = 2
  a = 1
  alist = []

  while not ((gcd(a, n)) == 1):
      a = a + 1

  while ((gcd(a, n)) == 1) & (a <= n) :
      alist.append(a)
      a = a + 1
      while not ((gcd(a, n)) == 1):
          a = a + 1

  timer = len(alist)
  while timer >= 0:
      for a in alist:
          if (a**k) % n == 1:
              timer = timer - 1
              if timer < 0:
                  break
              pass
          else:
              timer = len(alist)
              k = k + 1
  return k
```

---

The line where n is defined

```
   n = (p * q).bit_length
```

---

The line where the function is called

```
lambdaN = carmichael(n)
```

---

The error message

```
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
```

Comment: What is `gcd`? It would be very helpful if you told us what modules you are using

Comment: can you share the line where you call the function?

Comment: post the error message as text

Comment: @AgentBiscutt , gcd means Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers (otherwise known as highest common factor).

Comment: @LarrytheLlama Ahh, understandable

Comment: What is the value of `n` passed into the function?  Show us the code that defines `n` at the calling level.

Comment: Also, when you defined your lambda, you need: `lambdaN = lambda n: carmichael(n)`

Comment: Try: `print(type(n))`

Comment: @LarrytheLlama I think you're reading too much into the variable name `lambdaN`.  I doubt they meant to actually make a lambda function.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. In this code, you never call `carmichael()`, although that's not what the traceback says. It looks like the problem is `n = (p * q).bit_length`, since `int.bit_length` is a function. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete but minimal code, expected output, and actual output, i.e. the full error message. For more tips, see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing a *function*, not an integer, as the `n` parameter.

```
n = (p * q).bit_length
```

You forgot the parentheses `()` after the `bit_length` function.  Without the parentheses, you're not *calling* the function, you're just *referring* to it.

Comment: I'm very new to python and am not sure how to fix this, forgive me.

Comment: Show us the code that defines `n` in the calling scope.

Comment: Just updated where n is defined

Comment: See the edit to my answer.